# GIMP: Indexed (Gif), change white to transparent

Tags: color, gimp, transparency, gif

I have a 1-bit black-and-white GIF, I need to change the white into transparent.

How do I do it in GIMP?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your image mode to RGB: `Image -> Mode -> RGB`
2. Now you can change white to transparent: `Colors -> Color to Alpha...`
3. Change your image mode back to 1-bit: `Image -> Mode -> Indexed...`